# Search through and replace Escaped HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following link, when clicked it correctly adds the html stored in the onclick event into the page.

**The link:**

```
<a class="button small secondary add_confirmation_button" href="#" onclick="add_fields(this, &quot;confirmations&quot;, &quot;<div class=\&quot;fields\&quot;>\n  <fieldset>\n    <legend>Confirmation<\/legend>\n    <div class=\&quot;row\&quot;>\n      <div class=\&quot;medium-6 columns\&quot;>\n        <div class=\&quot;input select optional confirmation_builder_confirmations_responder_id\&quot;><label class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; for=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_responder_id\&quot;>Responder<\/label><select class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][responder_id]\&quot; id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_responder_id\&quot;><option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Responder<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>Suncoast Credit Union<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2\&quot;>State Street Bank and Trust Company<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;3\&quot;>AuburnBank<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>Robertson Banking Company<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;5\&quot;>Phenix-Girard Bank<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;select_responder\&quot;>Select a responder<\/option><\/select><\/div>\n      <\/div>\n      <div class=\&quot;medium-6 columns\&quot;>\n        <div class=\&quot;input date optional confirmation_builder_confirmations_confirm_as_of_close_on\&quot;><label class=\&quot;date optional\&quot; for=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_confirm_as_of_close_on_2i\&quot;>Confirm as of close on<\/label><select id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_confirm_as_of_close_on_2i\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][confirm_as_of_close_on(2i)]\&quot; class=\&quot;date optional\&quot;>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>January<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2\&quot;>February<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;3\&quot;>March<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>April<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;5\&quot;>May<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;6\&quot; selected=\&quot;selected\&quot;>June<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;7\&quot;>July<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;8\&quot;>August<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;9\&quot;>September<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;10\&quot;>October<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;11\&quot;>November<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;12\&quot;>December<\/option>\n        <\/select>\n        <select id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_confirm_as_of_close_on_3i\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][confirm_as_of_close_on(3i)]\&quot; class=\&quot;date optional\&quot;>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>1<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2\&quot;>2<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;3\&quot;>3<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>4<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;5\&quot;>5<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;6\&quot;>6<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;7\&quot;>7<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;8\&quot;>8<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;9\&quot;>9<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;10\&quot;>10<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;11\&quot;>11<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;12\&quot;>12<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;13\&quot;>13<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;14\&quot;>14<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;15\&quot;>15<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;16\&quot;>16<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;17\&quot;>17<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;18\&quot; selected=\&quot;selected\&quot;>18<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;19\&quot;>19<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;20\&quot;>20<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;21\&quot;>21<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;22\&quot;>22<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;23\&quot;>23<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;24\&quot;>24<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;25\&quot;>25<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;26\&quot;>26<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;27\&quot;>27<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;28\&quot;>28<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;29\&quot;>29<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;30\&quot;>30<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;31\&quot;>31<\/option>\n        <\/select>\n        <select id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_confirm_as_of_close_on_1i\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][confirm_as_of_close_on(1i)]\&quot; class=\&quot;date optional\&quot;>\n        <option value=\&quot;2015\&quot; selected=\&quot;selected\&quot;>2015<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2014\&quot;>2014<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2013\&quot;>2013<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2012\&quot;>2012<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2011\&quot;>2011<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2010\&quot;>2010<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2009\&quot;>2009<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2008\&quot;>2008<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2007\&quot;>2007<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2006\&quot;>2006<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2005\&quot;>2005<\/option>\n        <\/select>\n        <\/div>\n      <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <div class=\&quot;row\&quot;>\n      <div class=\&quot;medium-6 columns\&quot;>\n        <div class=\&quot;input select optional confirmation_builder_confirmations_client_id\&quot;><label class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; for=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_client_id\&quot;>Client<\/label><select class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][client_id]\&quot; id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_client_id\&quot;><option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Client<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;33\&quot;>A com<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>Boars Head<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;34\&quot;>Bobs co<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;32\&quot;>Dogs<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;24\&quot;>Example Company<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;new_client\&quot;>Add a new client<\/option><\/select><\/div>\n      <\/div>\n      <div class=\&quot;medium-6 columns\&quot;>\n        <div class=\&quot;input select optional confirmation_builder_confirmations_signer_id\&quot;><label class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; for=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_signer_id\&quot;>Signer<\/label><select class=\&quot;select optional\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][signer_id]\&quot; id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_signer_id\&quot;><option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Signer<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>Michael mickson<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;2\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;3\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;5\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;6\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;7\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;8\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;9\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;10\&quot;>joel<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;11\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;12\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;13\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;14\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;15\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;16\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;17\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;18\&quot;>t<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;19\&quot;>joel<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;20\&quot;>joel<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;21\&quot;>joel<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;22\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;23\&quot;>jo<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;24\&quot;>Michelle <\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;25\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;29\&quot;>MJ<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;30\&quot;>MJ<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;31\&quot;>John<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;32\&quot;>d<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;33\&quot;>Michael<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;34\&quot;>Michelle<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;35\&quot;>j<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;36\&quot;>b<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;new_signer\&quot;>Add a new signer<\/option><\/select><\/div>\n      <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <fieldset>\n      <legend>Account\'s<\/legend>\n      <p>\n        <a class=\&quot;button small secondary\&quot; href=\&quot;#\&quot; onclick=\&quot;add_fields(this, &amp;quot;accounts&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;&amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;fields\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\\n  &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;row\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;medium-4 columns\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\\n      &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;input string required confirmation_builder_confirmations_new_confirmations_accounts_account_id\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;label class=\\&amp;quot;string required\\&amp;quot; for=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_accounts_attributes_new_accounts_account_id\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;abbr title=\\&amp;quot;required\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;*&amp;lt;\\/abbr&amp;gt; Account Number&amp;lt;\\/label&amp;gt;&amp;lt;input class=\\&amp;quot;string required\\&amp;quot; type=\\&amp;quot;text\\&amp;quot; name=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][accounts_attributes][new_accounts][account_id]\\&amp;quot; id=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_accounts_attributes_new_accounts_account_id\\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;medium-4 columns\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\\n      &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;input select optional confirmation_builder_confirmations_new_confirmations_accounts_style\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;label class=\\&amp;quot;select optional\\&amp;quot; for=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_accounts_attributes_new_accounts_style\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Confirmation style&amp;lt;\\/label&amp;gt;&amp;lt;select class=\\&amp;quot;select optional\\&amp;quot; name=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][accounts_attributes][new_accounts][style]\\&amp;quot; id=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_accounts_attributes_new_accounts_style\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;option selected=\\&amp;quot;selected\\&amp;quot; value=\\&amp;quot;liability\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Liability&amp;lt;\\/option&amp;gt;\\n      &amp;lt;option value=\\&amp;quot;asset\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Asset&amp;lt;\\/option&amp;gt;\\n      &amp;lt;option value=\\&amp;quot;line_of_credit\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Line of credit&amp;lt;\\/option&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\\/select&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;div class=\\&amp;quot;medium-4 columns\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;\\n      &amp;lt;label for=\\&amp;quot;Remove\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Remove&amp;lt;\\/label&amp;gt;&amp;lt;input type=\\&amp;quot;hidden\\&amp;quot; value=\\&amp;quot;false\\&amp;quot; name=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][accounts_attributes][new_accounts][_destroy]\\&amp;quot; id=\\&amp;quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations_accounts_attributes_new_accounts__destroy\\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a class=\\&amp;quot;button tiny alert expand\\&amp;quot; href=\\&amp;quot;#\\&amp;quot; onclick=\\&amp;quot;remove_fields(this); return false;\\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;- Remove account&amp;lt;\\/a&amp;gt;\\n    &amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n  &amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;\\n&amp;lt;\\/div&amp;gt;&amp;quot;); return false;\&quot;>+ Add account<\/a>\n      <\/p>\n    <\/fieldset>\n    <input type=\&quot;hidden\&quot; value=\&quot;false\&quot; name=\&quot;confirmation_builder[confirmations_attributes][new_confirmations][_destroy]\&quot; id=\&quot;confirmation_builder_confirmations_attributes_new_confirmations__destroy\&quot; /><a class=\&quot;button tiny alert expand no_bottom_margin\&quot; href=\&quot;#\&quot; onclick=\&quot;remove_fields(this); return false;\&quot;>- Remove confirmation<\/a>\n  <\/fieldset>\n<\/div>&quot;); return false;">+ Add confirmation</a>
```

What can't figure out is how to append a select option to a select within the  onclick attribute.

**How to go about this?**

I want to find this:

`<option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Client<\/option>\n`

and replace it with:

`<option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Client<\/option>\n<option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>Client with id of 4<\/option>\n`

**Another Thought**

Aside from the find and replace method I mentioned; I thought there may be a way with jquery to convert the string into "something" that I could use the typical jquery selectors on. Then, I would find the select and append the option, then convert it back to its original escaped* state.

*not sure if escaped is the right word.

As a developer it's a problem that I don't know how to refer to the current state of the string. Is it escaped, unescaped?

Comment: I'd have to suggest that the `onclick` attribute is *not* the place to put all this code.

Comment: I doubt that your link as shown even works. `&quot;` is resolved to a simple `"` by _the HTML parser_, so the value of your onclick attribute will effectively be `onclick="add_fields(this, "confirmations", "<div …"); return false;"`, and that should break.

Comment: It does work, it's a pattern designed by RyanBates of railscasts for nested forms.

Comment: Nice. So I'll say it again; you're making a **lot** of work for yourself by not following reasonable practices, e.g., not putting **12K** of text into an HTML attribute. Create a method and pass in what you want to replace, or use a templating library.

Comment: Dave. You are of no help. I do not want your opinion on the structure of my application. I want an answer to the question. It's a shame when intelligent people can't follow simple instructions.

Comment: You don't get to decide how people react, and whether or not you *want* it, here it is. Part of the reason you're having a problem is because you have crufted up your code making it **significantly** more difficult to even understand where your issue lies. It is non-sensical to not pull this out into a method, stop with the completely unnecessary usage of the `&quot;` attribute (which isn't necessary anyway since you could just use single-quotes), and *greatly* simply both *your* life, and the lives of those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Regarding "following simple instructions", please show me where SO "instructs" people that general comments regarding code style and how to help people helping you is disallowed. If you have an issue, take it to meta.

Comment: Dave, if you are so intelligent then submit an answer to the question. Your comments in their current state are of no use to me.

Comment: Too bad; you're ignoring good advice (which is mirrored, by the way, in the existing answer, and is one of the two suggestions I made). You already have three solutions (the two I offered and the similar answer). Your HTML/code is illegible as written. It's OK (but disturbing) you don't care, but I'd suggest not getting snippy because someone thinks it's worth trying to clean it up. Not to mention it would make the answer to the question much easier to discuss. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex and try to append to your existing `onclick` function, it would be easier to save it on a string then later when you finish you use `.prop` or `.attr` to change the `onclick` function..

```
var before_option = "add_fields(this, &quot;confirmations&quot;,  ...";
var after_option = "... <option value=\&quot;33\&quot;>A com<\/option>\n        <option value=\&quot;1\&quot;>Boars Head<\/option>\n";

//Let's say you need to click a button to add that option
$("#click_button").click(function(){
    var options = "<option value=\&quot;\&quot;>Select Client<\/option>\n<option value=\&quot;4\&quot;>Client with id of 4<\/option>\n";
    var final_option = before_option + options +  after_option;
    $(".add_confirmation_button").prop("onclick", final_option);
});
```